# How do I implement iOS 9's UICollectionView interactive movement features?

Tags: ios, swift, layout, uicollectionview, uikit

iOS 9 added the ability tap and hold to rearrange collection view cells with minimal effort. Enabling this capability in the trivial situation is straightforward. Simply implement one function on your `UICollectionViewController`.

`func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, moveItemAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath)`

If you want more documentation on that function see its definition in `UICollectionViewDataSource`.

This doesn't *just work* with a custom layout though. What does it take to make it work in a more complex case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't well documented, but there are 2 mandatory overrides for this to work correctly. In your `UICollectionViewLayout` subclass implement the following 2 functions

```
override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
    return self.itemAttributes.filter { $0.frame.intersects(rect) }
}
```

First you need to make sure that the item attributes from your layout are filtered to *only* include the attributes in the given rect. If you include more, it gets confused.

```
override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
    return self.itemAttributes.first(where: { $0.indexPath.item == indexPath.item })
}
```

Not sure why this is necessary, you'd think that UIKit could infer the correct attributes based on previous calls, but it can't. Anyway, you just need to be able to fetch the correct attributes for the given indexPath.